# Sum values on groupby on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I'm working on a dataset from some old kagle competicion,

I want to make some aggregations from one of the tables:

To know on which days the disscount  is bigger, my expected output is like this:

[image]
[image]

For that I tried with this code:

```
coupon_list[[ 'USABLE_DATE_MON', 'USABLE_DATE_TUE', 'USABLE_DATE_WED',
       'USABLE_DATE_THU', 'USABLE_DATE_FRI', 'USABLE_DATE_SAT',
       'USABLE_DATE_SUN','DISCOUNT_PRICE']].melt("DISCOUNT_PRICE").groupby("variable").agg({"DISCOUNT_PRICE":sum,"value":sum})
```

But for that aggregation the disscount_price is the average of all the table, not the average by day.

[image]

To solve this I created a new table:

```
coupon_list_usable["DISCOUNT_PRICE"] =  coupon_list_usable.apply(lambda x: x.DISCOUNT_PRICE if x.value==1 else 0,axis=1 )

coupon_list_usable.groupby("variable").agg({"DISCOUNT_PRICE":sum,"value":sum}).reset_index()[["variable","DISCOUNT_PRICE"]].set_index("variable").plot.bar()
```

But isn't a pythonic solution, is it possible to do this in the groupby itself?

Comment: It would be much easier to help if you gave us code to instantiate a sample dataframe (I don't want to type it in by hand) and the output you expect for that sample. Currently, even if I had the correct solution, I would not post it because I can't test it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) forfor filter rows with `1` and for aggregate  use [`GroupBy.sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html):

*Notice: `dropna` here cannot be used, because there are also `2` values in data of days columns.*

```
s = (coupon_list.melt("DISCOUNT_PRICE")
                 .query('value == 1')
                 .groupby("variable")['DISCOUNT_PRICE']
                 .sum())

s.plot.bar()
```

You can also change ordering of days with `reindex` or by `ordered Categorical`s:

```
days = ['USABLE_DATE_MON', 'USABLE_DATE_TUE', 'USABLE_DATE_WED',
       'USABLE_DATE_THU', 'USABLE_DATE_FRI', 'USABLE_DATE_SAT',
       'USABLE_DATE_SUN']

s = (coupon_list.melt("DISCOUNT_PRICE")
                 .query('value == 1')
                 .groupby("variable")['DISCOUNT_PRICE']
                 .sum()
                 .reindex(days))
```

---

```
days = ['USABLE_DATE_MON', 'USABLE_DATE_TUE', 'USABLE_DATE_WED',
       'USABLE_DATE_THU', 'USABLE_DATE_FRI', 'USABLE_DATE_SAT',
       'USABLE_DATE_SUN']

s = (coupon_list.melt("DISCOUNT_PRICE", var_name='days', value_name='data')
                .assign(days = lambda x: pd.Categorical(x['days'], 
                                                        ordered=True, 
                                                        categories=days))
                .query('value == 1')
                .groupby("days")['DISCOUNT_PRICE']
                .sum())
```

**Sample**:

```
coupon_list = pd.DataFrame({
         'USABLE_DATE_MON':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,1,1,np.nan],
         'USABLE_DATE_TUE':[1,np.nan,1,np.nan,1,np.nan],
         'USABLE_DATE_WED':[1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,1,1],
         'USABLE_DATE_THU':[1,1,np.nan,1,1,np.nan],
         'USABLE_DATE_FRI':[np.nan,1,2,np.nan,1,np.nan],
         'USABLE_DATE_SAT':[1,1,np.nan,1,1,2],
         'USABLE_DATE_SUN':[1,np.nan,1,1,1,1],
         'DISCOUNT_PRICE':[2,3,6,2,2,4],
})
print (coupon_list)
   USABLE_DATE_MON  USABLE_DATE_TUE  USABLE_DATE_WED  USABLE_DATE_THU  \
0              NaN              1.0              1.0              1.0   
1              NaN              NaN              NaN              1.0   
2              NaN              1.0              NaN              NaN   
3              1.0              NaN              NaN              1.0   
4              1.0              1.0              1.0              1.0   
5              NaN              NaN              1.0              NaN   

   USABLE_DATE_FRI  USABLE_DATE_SAT  USABLE_DATE_SUN  DISCOUNT_PRICE  
0              NaN              1.0              1.0               2  
1              1.0              1.0              NaN               3  
2              2.0              NaN              1.0               6  
3              NaN              1.0              1.0               2  
4              1.0              1.0              1.0               2  
5              NaN              2.0              1.0               4
```

---

```
days = ['USABLE_DATE_MON', 'USABLE_DATE_TUE', 'USABLE_DATE_WED',
       'USABLE_DATE_THU', 'USABLE_DATE_FRI', 'USABLE_DATE_SAT',
       'USABLE_DATE_SUN']

s = (coupon_list.melt("DISCOUNT_PRICE", var_name='days', value_name='data')
                .assign(days = lambda x: pd.Categorical(x['days'], 
                                                        ordered=True, 
                                                        categories=days))
                .query('data == 1')
                .groupby("days")['DISCOUNT_PRICE']
                .sum())

print (s)
days
USABLE_DATE_MON     4
USABLE_DATE_TUE    10
USABLE_DATE_WED     8
USABLE_DATE_THU     9
USABLE_DATE_FRI     5
USABLE_DATE_SAT     9
USABLE_DATE_SUN    16
Name: DISCOUNT_PRICE, dtype: int64

s.plot.bar()
```

[image: graph]